# Blazor webassembly in Angular project

Tags: angular, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor webassembly web application, and i want to add it to an Angular project. I have researched to solution, but i didn't found anything that can help me. is there anynone who has idea over how can i combine Angular en Blazor together?

Comment: just wanted to know, why do you need to add Blazor WASM into Angular project?

Comment: because i have a .Net methodes in one component. I want to add this component to my Angular app to my exisiting Angular app

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use Blazor components inside an core Angular app. However standalone Angular elements Web component may use inside Blazor WASM app using JavaScript Interop feature.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?
I think its a concept that would be valuable to many who have existing angular applications

Comment: May be you should take the .Net methods into a rest server that you call from your Angular project

Answer (score 4):

Starting from .NET 7 you can seamlessly [use Blazor components in any javascript application](https://youtu.be/sMOGPRbsbcs?t=6689)

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options => {
    options.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Counter>("blazor-counter");
});
```

In angular

```
<blazor-counter></blazor-counter>
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to make the Blazor component(s) available for instantiation from JavaScript by calling [`JSComponentConfigurationExtensions.RegisterForJavaScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.jscomponentconfigurationextensions.registerforjavascript), which is available from ASP.NET Core 6.0 on.

Bridging the gap from a Blazor component to an Angular component requires some further steps. The [JavaScript Component Generation](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/main/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/JSComponentGeneration) sample from the ASP.NET samples shows them, however the provided code does not compile at the time of this writing because of some open issues.

Based on this code, I've created a demo project which includes all these steps builds successfully. See my [BlazorInAngularDemo github project](https://github.com/Xenoage/BlazorInAngularDemo) for the code and description and a [working demo](https://xenoage.github.io/BlazorInAngularDemo/#/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Go ahead, but get ready for a copious amount of manual work.

Loot at the very first part of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0) manual. It shows you how to use `Blazor.Start` javascript function to bootstrap your WASM into an HTML file. You can just take all built resources, transfer them to your Angular project and run `Blazor.Start`.

You should be able to use JS interop to talk to your Angular app.